# How to effectively deploy Arcana synergy spells?

Tags: the-last-remnant

I've unlocked the Blackout arcana, which is very useful for clearing the field, but so far I haven't been able to figure out how to deploy it on command. How do these Arts work and what do I need to do to be able to pull them off with a good success rate?

Comment: this might help you out: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/939444-the-last-remnant/47691330

Comment: @spartacus there's some interesting information, but the mechanics are still mysterious to me.

Answer (score 1):

Arcana arts, once learned, can be queued by a high morale bar (~85% in your favor), just like a (UA) Unique Art or a (WA) Weapon Art. You can also activate it via Synergy by having the appropriate troops in the union cast the spells you need.

To be able to learn them with a higher rate, you might want to add more units that know the specific area (or not, it depends on the Arcana) to trigger a higher chance that 3/4 of them will cast a spell (Invocations > Blackout).

Some arts you can actually learn better by using specific formations, such as Orb formation (-2 AP cost) and Mystic Seal (10% Remedies Heal rate, forces many of my Remedies users to cast arts, making RW easier to get).

Btw, Mystic Seal and I couldn't heal both my HP cap unions with my 5 remedies users at Revitalize V :)

There are guides on GameFAQs on what spells your leader needs to learn the Arcana, so I won't go into much detail on that.

The almighty wiki: http://lastremnant.wikia.com/wiki/Mystic_Arts#Arcana